# java how to get user input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

What is the difference between

```
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer= keyboard.nextInt();
```

and

```
        int answer= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

I am a beginner here so thorough explanation would help a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what a (local) variable is?

Comment: no difference. first you assign the Scanner to a variable and in the next example you don't. they are equal, but the first one is more equal than the other.

Comment: There is no difference, except that you can't reuse the Scanner instance of the second snippet.

Comment: There is no difference. In the first case, you just assign your "new Scanner" in a local variable whereas in the second case you directly use the "new Scanner". The first case can be useful if you have to read several user input in the same method, the second one is enough if you only have one user input at a time.

Comment: @C-Otto Yes, I do know what local variable is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
int answer= keyboard.nextInt();
```

In the above code a `Scanner` object is created in the heap memory and its reference is stored in a variable called `keyboard`(`keyboard` varible is stored in stack memory). Using variable `keyboard` you can able access the `Scanner` object at any point of the program.

```
 int answer= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

In the second statement you are creating object which is also stored in heap memory , but the reference of the object is not stored in any variable. So you cannot able to access this object anymore. After this statement the object in heap memory are ready to be garbage collected , since its reference is not used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement initializes a Scanner object that can be used multiple times.

The second statement creates a new Scanner object for just that line of code. You would have to call a new Scanner object next time you need input.

It is better practice to create the variable than to create a new object each time.

Comment: If the input I need from a user is only "answer" and I am using this in a loop, second code would suffice, right?

Comment: `for (int i; i<10; i++){
    int answer= new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    System.out.println(answer);
        }`

Comment: As I was saying, that code would work, but programming conventions would prefer that you declare the Scanner object before you use it,

Comment: (Accidentally pressed send). It makes the code easier to read and understand.